# This code keeps telling me I need to update Google Play Services. How do I fix that?

Tags: android, gradle, location, google-play-services

This is my MainActivity.java.  It keeps saying i need to update google play services, but I thought I had already installed them in build.gradle.  Please let me know if you see the problem.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private static int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES = 200;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (checkGooglePlayServices()) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        //prepare connection request
        createLocationRequest();
    }
}






private boolean checkGooglePlayServices() {

    int checkGooglePlayServices = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (checkGooglePlayServices != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
          /*
           * google play services is missing or update is required
           *  return code could be
           * SUCCESS,
           * SERVICE_MISSING, SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED,
           * SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_INVALID.
           */
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(checkGooglePlayServices,
                this, REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES).show();

        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                    !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services must be installed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude:" + mLastLocation.getLatitude()+", Longitude:"+mLastLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    startLocationUpdates();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}


/* Second part*/

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(20000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Update -> Latitude:" + mLastLocation.getLatitude()+", Longitude:"+mLastLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }


}
}
```

This is my build.gradle folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.usinglocationiapi.usinglocationapi"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'



}
```

Comment: AFAIK `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` will check if the version of Google Play Services on the device is up to date and return an error if it's not up to date. `getErrorDialog` will then return the dialog that asks the user to update Google Play Services. Not sure if you can do anything about this, since Google probably will keep releasing new updates. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview) to get an idea of how the Google Play Services client library and the Google Play Services APK fit together.

Answer (score 0):

[image]8.3.0 is not the latest version of google play services. Change the 8.3.0 to 8.4.+

EDIT: okay try out this, go to Tools - Android - SDK managaer and update your google play services sdk. I'm not sure if it will fix your problem, but give it a try..

Comment: I tried changing it to 8.4.0 and 8.4.+ but the gradle build failed both times, saying it was unable to download the repositories.  Could you please show me what a functional gradle folder would look like on this situation?

Comment: there is an update available, but the checkbox has a black line through the middle.  When I click Apply, it doesn't work.

Comment: @felix click the checkbox until its a tick like shown in the pic. Then press Ok and it tells you it will update it..